# Need tips for better usability for tabular data with pagination

Tags: asp.net, usability

Just another day i found myself writing code to show data on the UI.

1. I am again using DataGrid/GridView (ASP.NET),
2. User Id as link button (clickable) to redirect user to another page.
3. User having hard time to find where to click(Though the link has underline and hand pointer as usual on hover)
4. just another common table like structure

Following are the columns for example,
User ID (Link button), User Name, First Name, Last Name, Date Of Birth

Now i would like to make it better form the usability point of view. Can someone suggest a good link, example or suggestions to make it better.

Thanks all,

Answer (score 1):

how about changing the user id column to a button to make it more clear that it's clickable?
you could also add a new button/link column that says "edit" or "view" instead of making the user id the link to the next page.

Comment: +1: Add another column that says "Edit" on every row in the table.